# Could not find appcompat.jar

Tags: android-studio, react-native, androidx

somebody help me with this i could not migrate to androidx

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find appcompat.jar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.jar